# How can i convert images from scikit-image to opencv2 and other libraries?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, scikit-image

I tried to find contour with cv2 python library in a skeletonized image created with scikit-image and i got this error:

```
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(skel,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
TypeError: <unknown> data type = 0 is not supported
```

My question is: What i have to do to convert to cv2 and viceversa?

I know that opencv use numpy.uint8 type to represent binary images instead scikit-image numpy.float64

I used also mahotas (numpy.bool) and pymorph libraries.
How can i convert from scikit-image to these libraries and viceversa?

Comment: I think i found myself solution! If i use:     skel = np.array(skel, dtype=np.uint8) i easily convert in opencv2 type and so on for other libraries!

Comment: http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html#using-an-image-from-skimage-with-opencv

Answer (score 19):

`scikit-image` provides conversion routines between the different data-types that also correctly preserves scaling:

```
from skimage import img_as_ubyte

cv_image = img_as_ubyte(any_skimage_image)
```

Update: the scikit-image user guide now has a more detailed section on this: http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/user_guide/data_types.html#working-with-opencv

Comment: What would be vice versa variant: from cv_image to skimage?

Comment: If cv_image is an array of unsigned bytes, skimage will understand it by default.  If you prefer working with floating point images, `img_as_float` should do the trick.  See the skimage user guide for more information.

Comment: Also, whoever will need these conversions, keep in mind that OpenCV use BGR color space by default while Skimage use RGB one :-)

Comment: That's a good reminder, thanks Yuriy. I'll file an issue on the scikit-image docs to add a section on this conversion. (https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2500)

Comment: Answer update above with link to new section in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
image = skimage.io.imread(mpath)
img = image[:, :, ::-1] # convert image from RGB (skimage) to BGR (opencv)
cv2.namedWindow('original', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('original',img)
```